# Удалить дубликаты из ячейки

Tags: excel

Подсмотрел у жены задачу. Есть лист эксель с ячейками:

[image: дубли в ячейчах]

Нужно найти и удалить все задвоения чисел внутри каждой ячейки.

Пример:

Есть ячейка 53 45 67 89 23 53 45

Нужно оставить только первое вхождение 53, а второе - удалить. (Дополнение от A K -- видимо и 45, тоже дублируется)

Есть ли какие-то простые способы сделать это? Я бы пошёл путём написания макроса (повод вспомнить vba), но может есть какие-то готовые встроенные функции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть способ, но вряд ли будет проще :)

Применим на небольшом количестве ячеек с данными. Тест: диапазон из 30 ячеек обработан за 4 минуты.

Выделить диапазон, закладка *Данные-Текст_по_столбцам-с_разделителями-Далее*, разделитель *пробел-Готово*. Получили каждое число в отдельной ячейке.

Правее в верхней строке диапазона (в примере - строка 4) пишем формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ПОИСКПОЗ(A4:I4;A4:I4;)=СТОЛБЕЦ(A4:I4);A4:I4)
```

Протягиваем формулу по всем строкам. Формула может показывать ошибку - ничего срашного.

Дальше нудное (чем больше строк, тем дольше): выделить формулу в строке формул, последовательно нажать *F9-Enter* - получим результат вычислений формулы. Для исходного текста  *53 45 67 89 23 53 45* полученный результат:

```
={53;45;67;89;23;ЛОЖЬ;ЛОЖЬ;#Н/Д;#Н/Д}
```

После преобразования всех формул выделить диапазон с формулами, с помощью инструмента *НАЙТИ/ЗАМЕНИТЬ* удалить знаки и выражения

*=* (равно), *{}* (фигурные скобки каждая отдельно), *ЛОЖЬ*, *#Н/Д*

Сдвоенную точку с запятой (;;) заменить несколько раз на точку с запятой.

Точку с запятой (;) заменить на пробел. В ячейках останутся уникальные числа, записанные через пробел. Последний штрих: удалить использованные столбцы.

```
----------------------
```

Поигрались? Теперь возвращаем данные на место и обрабатываем макросом :)

```
Sub DelDuplNum()
Dim ar(), aSpl
Dim lRw As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, p As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRw < 4 Then Exit Sub
        ar = .Range("A1:A" & lRw).Value

        For i = 4 To lRw
            aSpl = Split(ar(i, 1), " "): ar(i, 1) = aSpl(0)

            For j = 0 To UBound(aSpl) - 1
                For p = j + 1 To UBound(aSpl)
                    If aSpl(j) <> "" Then
                        If aSpl(j) = aSpl(p) Then aSpl(p) = ""
                    End If
                Next p
            Next j

            For j = 0 To UBound(aSpl)
                If aSpl(j) <> "" Then ar(i, 1) = ar(i, 1) & " " & aSpl(j)
            Next j
        Next i

        .Range("A1:A" & lRw).Value = ar
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Сложно))) Или мне кажется?

Comment: Нет, не сложно, но при большом количестве строк муторно менять каждую формулу. С Notepad++ проще )

Answer (score 4):

1. Скопировать столбец в Notepad++
2. Заменить `(\b(\d+)\b.*) \2\b` на `\1` с использованием регулярных выражений
3. Нажимать <kbd>Заменить все</kbd> до тех пор, пока не получится 0 замен
4. Скопировать получившиеся данные и вставить обратно в Excel

[image: Скриншот диалога замены в NPP]

Comment: пробелы удаляет! :)

Comment: @teran, эм.. а надо было числа удалять и создавать при этом повторяющиеся пробелы? Если да, то удали пробел перед `\2`. Но вообще-то это странно, не?

Comment: я проверил на строке `1 2 3 1 2 3 22 21 11` получил `1 2 32 3 22 21 11` он после первой замены удалил вторую единицу и пробелы вокруг, в результате склеились 3 и 2 которые были вокруг.

Comment: видимо имеет  смысл заменить не на `\1` а на `_\1` (`_` - пробел), а затем заменить двойные пробелы одинарными

Comment: @teran, исправил. Я почему-то не подумал, что `\b` не является частью совпадения и ожидал, что оно сработает само))

Comment: Я подумал и решил оставить галку на более 'excel way' ответе (по сути, там даже два способа), однако лично мне вариант с регуляркой в  Notepad++  кажется более изящным и достойным дополнительной награды.

Comment: @AK, я вообще удивился, что в самом экселе регулярки не поддерживаются. Но вариант из принятого ответа тоже интересный :)

Comment: Регулярки в Excel поддерживаются, но я в них хромаю. Но регулярки - это тоже макросом, а предпочтительным было решение без VBA.

Comment: @vikttur, ну с vba-то всё можно. Просто в текстовых редакторах обычно в find&replace есть регулярки, а тут нет. И формулы с регулярками в гуглотаблицах есть, а в экселе - нет.

Answer (score 4):

**Полу-*VBA*** :)

Вариант решения с помощью функции пользователя и использования в ней словарей.

В общем модуле разместить код:

```
Function DelDupl(r As Range) As String
Dim aSpl, txt
    aSpl = Split(r, " ")

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each txt In aSpl: .Item(txt) = 0&: Next txt
        DelDupl = Join(.keys, " ")
    End With
End Function
```

В ячейку строки с данными вписать формулу:

```
=DelDupl(A4)
```

Протянуть по строкам. При желании выделить диапазон строк, копировать, *Вставить_как_значения*

Примечание: на *MAC*'е не применять, он со словарями не работает.

```
' --------------
```

**Совсем без VBA и ручного вмешательства**

Вариант1. Проще и понятнее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а) Разбиваем по ячейкам. Формула в *D4* (копируется в диапазон *D:M*):

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(" "&$A4;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)*99;99))
```

б) Удаляем повторы. Формула в N4 (копируется в диапазон *N:W*):

```
=ЕСЛИ(ПОИСКПОЗ(D4;$D4:$M4;)=СТОЛБЕЦ(A1);D4;"")&" "
```

в) Показываем результат. Формула в *B4* (копируется в столбец *B*):

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(N4&O4&P4&Q4&R4&S4&T4&U4&V4&W4)
```

Вариант2. Формула сложнее и непонятнее )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а) Разбиваем по ячейкам и удаляем повторы. Формула в *D4* (копируется в диапазон *D:M*):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($C4:C4;СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(" "&$A4;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)*99;99))&" ");"";СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(" "&$A4;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)*99;99))&" ")
```

б) Показываем результат. Формула в *B4* (копируется в столбец *B*):

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(D4&E4&F4&G4&H4&I4&J4&K4&L4&M4)
```

Вариант3. Одной формулой.

Практически невозможен, т.к. нужно сздавать в памяти массивы, а текстовые функции не умеют работать в формулах массива.

Comment: Отдельным ответом, чтобы не нарушать логику комментариев. Но, может, неправ и стоит ответы объединить в один?

Comment: [Я предпочитаю один развёрнутый ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3558/213987) с вариантами решения проблемы, но встречал тех, кто упорно пишет в разные. Вы автор -- вам и решать.

Comment: @AK, а я предпочитаю отдельные ответы.

Comment: Паритет :) Подождем еще мнение. Как удобнее воспринимать?

Answer (score 2):

Все предыдущие решения требуют либо VBA либо дополнительных действий, т.е. не будут работать при динамическом изменении данных. Единственное ограничение в моем решении - кол-во чисел в исходной строке, для 2010 Excel - кол-во столбцов 16384, значит в исходной строке не может быть больше (16384-2)/4=4095 чисел. Можно объединить 5 и 6 блоки, тогда чисел может быть 5460.

[image: скриншот excel]

Формулы:

Блок 1: Исходная строка

Блок 2: Уникальные значения

`B3` `=AL3`

Блок 3: Позиция пробела (для разбивки строки на отдельные числа)

`C3` `=ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(" ";$A3;1));ДЛСТР($A3)+1;НАЙТИ(" ";$A3;1))`

`D3 - K3` `=ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(" ";$A3;C3+1));ДЛСТР($A3)+1;НАЙТИ(" ";$A3;C3+1))`

Блок 4: Числа из исходной текстовой строки

`L3` `=ПСТР($A3;1;C3-1)`

`M3 - T3` `=ЕСЛИ(D3>C3;ПСТР($A3;C3+1;D3-C3-1);"")`

Блок 5: Определяем "уникальность" числа (считаем сколько раз это число встречается от начала блока то текущего столбца, если 1 - то число уникально)

`U3 - AC3` `=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($L3:L3;L3)`

Блок 6: Сцепляем уникальные числа, отделяя их друг от друга пробелами

`AD3` `=ЕСЛИ(U3=1;L3;"")`

`AE3 - AL3` `=ЕСЛИ(V3=1;СЦЕПИТЬ(AD3;" ";M3);AD3)`

Comment: Формулами можно проще. Добавил варианты в свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

У меня была аналогичная задача. Нашел код, который:

1. мне абсолютно непонятен.
2. работает как нужно.

---

Выделить диапазон, запустить макрос

```vb
Sub bb()
    Dim c As Range, x
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") ' создаем объект - словарь
        For Each c In Selection ' цикл по выделенному диапазону
            .RemoveAll ' чистим словарь

            ' при заполнении словаря метод Item позволяет
            ' обходить ошибку при добавлении дубля ключа
            ' ранее записанное значение заменяется новым
            ' т. е. практически - удаление дублей
            For Each x In Split(c) ' цикл по фрагментам текста
                .Item(x) = 0
            Next

            ' массив, состоящий из всех ключей, имеющихся в коллекции
            c = Join(.keys)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Практически то же самое в ответе *"Полу VBA"*. Добавил комментарии к коду. Это коротко, я слабо знаком со словарями. Поиск *"scripting.dictionary"*, информации много.