# Как найти строки совпадающие после разделителя?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Сейчас используется выражение: `^(.+)[ -].+$\s+?^(?=.*^\1).+$`

оно удаляет дубли в текстовых документах ориентируясь до разделителя который указан в квадратных скобках, а не по целой строке.

Например:

нужно чтобы такие строки удалялись

342434-1111
435345-1111

а данное выражение удаляет строки если дубли слева

1111-43423
1111-34535

Используется в Notepad++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы удалились указанные строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну зачем минусовать-то? Вопрос нормальный, задача вполне себе практическая, работа автора вполне видна.

Comment: @AK, посмотрите историю правок, чья работа там видна... После правки я изменил минус на плюс, чего и другим рекомендую. В данном виде вопрос норм.

Comment: Для чистки дублей хорошо помогает эксель, особенно когда текст структурированный и можно по ячейкам распихать. [Вот например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688082/213987), я спрашивал как-то вопрос, мне подсказали пару красивых способов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68338/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Базовая регулярка на одну с предпросмотром следующей

```
^(.+)[ -](.+)$\s+(?=^(.+)[ -](.+)$)
```

Теперь надо заменить одну из групп второй строки на обратную ссылку:

```
^(.+)[ -](.+)$\s+(?=^\1[ -](.+)$)
^(.+)[ -](.+)$\s+(?=^(.+)[ -]\2$)
```

Кстати, предполагаетсЯ, что строка содержит единственный дефис или пробел.

Comment: @василийпупкин, первая - вообще для пониания. Две в блоке кода - первая удаляет с одинаковыми левыми частями, вторая - с одинаковыми правыми. Именно это я вижу на видео. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY4Ew.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSALd.png - красным помечены строки, которые должны исчезнуть и они исчезают. PS: Замену можно отменять кнопкой отмены действия или нажатием ctrl+z.

Comment: ну хотя бы так, спасибо вам!  вы и так на меня много времени потратили

Comment: @василийпупкин, так ты ж это и просил?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68353/discussion-between-qwertiy-and--).